# typescript in angular2, how to access class variables through this

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, this

Given this code, how can I access to the object "sessions"? it fails due to "this" being null:

```
/// <reference path="chrome/chrome-app.d.ts" />

import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
    templateUrl: './templates/app.html',
    providers: [ AppService ]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public sessions : Object;
    constructor( private appService : AppService ) {}

    getBookmarkLists() {
        console.log(this.sessions) // it gives undefined
        this.sessions['test'] = 'yea'; // it fails
        this.appService.getBookmarks().then(function(bookmarks : any) {
            console.log(this.sessions) // it fails
        });

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getBookmarkLists();
    }
 }
```

What I would expect is to be able to access to the variable and populate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't initialized this `Sessions` object anywhere, should be as far I know:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public sessions: Session[] = []; // You forgot here to initialize it
    constructor( private appService : AppService ) {}

    getBookmarkLists() {
        console.log(this.sessions) // no it shouldn't give undefined
        this.sessions['test'] = 'yea'; // and this shouldn't fail
        this.appService.getBookmarks().then((bookmarks : any) => {
            // this should be an arrow function or function bound to use it
            // otherwise this will point to the function itself.
            console.log(this.sessions) // it shouldn't fail
        });

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getBookmarkLists();
    }
}
```

with the `sessions = [];` being the crucial part. 
So it's not only an issue of `this` which references the class instance in methods as it should.

The callback passed to the `then` should be an arrow function not a *classic* function, to keep the `this` reference to the class instance.

Comment: Yes, that's it, now I can access to sessions (but apparently not to their content, but I'd say this is unrelated to this question so big thanks!)